# Javascript upload image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, canvas

I want to upload image file and show on the canvas.
So I wrote the code like below

HTML code here

```html
<div class="img_upload">
    <input type="file" id="real-input" class="input-btn" accept="img/*" required multiple>
    <button class="browse-btn">Image Upload</botton>
</div>

<canvas id="jsCanvas" class="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

javascript code here

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#jsCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const browseBtn = document.querySelector('.browse-btn');
const realInput = document.querySelector('#real-input');

function readInputFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files;

    const img = new Image();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// button act like input tag
browseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    realInput.click();
});


realInput.addEventListener('change', readInputFile);
```

but `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);` doesn't work.

I check the img of value `console.log(img)`, then it's value is `<img src="incoding very long base 64 data">`
And I could see the image after I wrote `body.appendChild(img);`.

How can I active drawImage on canvas? What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i change your code try this:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#jsCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const realInput = document.querySelector('#real-input');
realInput.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);


function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

```html
<div class="img_upload">
   <input type="file" id="real-input" class="input-btn" accept="img/*" required multiple>
 
</div>

<canvas id="jsCanvas" class="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: wow! I missed `img.onload` ?? It's perfectly worked! Thank you